# Differentiation term by term of Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose I have A Taylor Series of a function around $z_{0}$ in the complex plane which convergence in a ball of radius $r>0$. Can I differentiate term by term the Taylor series and get the derivative of f?

If so, can you please proof it? else, give an example why is it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the taylor series as a power series about $z_0$ with radius of convergence $r$.
If $f(z)$ denotes the series, then we know that the derivative $f'(z)$ is found by differentiating the series term by term. For the proof, you can look up John B. Conway's 'Function of one complex variable', Proposition 2.5, which is available in internet.

So I think you are right.